# Focus any particular div in body just like bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have designed page using boostrap .

My intention is to focus a div in the body and everything else should get changed into gray or whatever similar to Bootstrap Modal . 
when i apply a div with background color gray, it overlaps the focus div also ..

**Fiddle :** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9QqPY/).

**focue CSS ::**

```
    .infocus
{
z-index: 1050;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #999;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
-moz-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
outline: none;
}
```

This is the  fiddle i have tried , i have copied bootstrap class for above purpose. is there any other idea to show particular div in focus.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the CSS `z-index` property, you must have the `position` property set to something other than `static` (http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/). Here's an updated, working, version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DBkWu/

Essentially, I added `position: absolute` to your `.infocus` class:

```
.infocus
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1050;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    outline: none;
}
```